# Correct way to initialize empty slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

To declare an empty slice, with a non-fixed size,
is it better to do:

```
mySlice1 := make([]int, 0)
```

or:

```
mySlice2 := []int{}
```

Just wondering which one is the correct way.

Comment: You say "non-fixed size", but slices are *never* have a fixed size. Unless you mean with zero capacity. Note, if you have an idea/guess/hint of what capacity you might need then using the three argument version is good. E.g. to build a slice of map keys: `keys := make([]int, 0, len(m)); for k, v := range m { keys := append(keys,k) }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare slice or make slice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543520/declare-slice-or-make-slice)

Answer (score 467, accepted):

The two alternative you gave are semantically identical, but using `make([]int, 0)` will result in an internal call to *runtime.makeslice* (Go 1.16).

You also have the option to leave it with a `nil` value:

```
var myslice []int
```

As written in the [Golang.org blog](http://blog.golang.org/slices):

> a nil slice is functionally equivalent to a zero-length slice, even though it points to nothing. It has length zero and can be appended to, with allocation.

A `nil` slice will however `json.Marshal()` into `"null"` whereas an empty slice will marshal into `"[]"`, as pointed out by  @farwayer.

None of the above options will cause any allocation, as pointed out by @ArmanOrdookhani.

Comment: Also mention on wiki https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#declaring-empty-slices

Comment: Be care: `json.Marshal()` will return `null` for `var myslice []int` and `[]` for initialized slice `myslice := []int{}`

Comment: Also be careful: `reflect.DeepEqual` makes a distinction between nil slices and non-nil slices: `a := []int{}`, `var b []int`, `reflect.DeepEqual(a, b) // returns false`

Comment: Why you think it would do an allocation? Cap is zero so nothing is allocated. All pointers to zero length things point to the same location in memory: https://play.golang.org/p/MPOKKl_sYvw

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani You are correct. I tried it out, and I also found out that I was wrong with my assumption on identical assembly instructions. Fixed!

Comment: “Semantically identical.” Are those identical in performance, too? Does the internal call make it slower than the one without `make(…)`?

Comment: @КонстантинВан As of Go 1.16, they don't produce identical code, as you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gj7so7ETx). Using _make_ calls [`runtime.makeslice`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#makeslice), even for a zero-length slice, while the empty slice literal directly uses [`runtime.zerobase`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#zerobase). Meaning, the literal is slightly faster in Go 1.16.

Comment: Is there a way to change the behavior of `json.Marshal` so that it returns `[]` for a `nil` slice?

Answer (score 131):

They are equivalent. See this code:

```
mySlice1 := make([]int, 0)
mySlice2 := []int{}
fmt.Println("mySlice1", cap(mySlice1))
fmt.Println("mySlice2", cap(mySlice2))
```

Output:

```
mySlice1 0
mySlice2 0
```

Both slices have `0` capacity which implies both slices have `0` length (cannot be greater than the capacity) which implies both slices have no elements. This means the 2 slices are identical in every aspect.

See similar questions:

[What is the point of having nil slice and empty slice in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104157/what-is-the-point-of-having-nil-slice-and-empty-slice-in-golang)

[nil slices vs non-nil slices vs empty slices in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305170/nil-slices-vs-non-nil-slices-vs-empty-slices-in-go-language/44305910#44305910)

Answer (score 68):

As an addition to [@ANisus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694331/anisus) answer...

below is some information from the *"Go in action"* book, which I think is worth mentioning:

### Difference between `nil` & `empty` slices

If we think of a slice like this:

```
[pointer] [length] [capacity]
```

then:

```
nil slice:   [nil][0][0]
empty slice: [addr][0][0] // points to an address
```

> #### nil slice
>
> They’re useful when you want to represent a slice that doesn’t exist, such as when an exception occurs in a function that returns a slice.
>
> ```
> // Create a nil slice of integers.
> var slice []int
> ```
>
> #### empty slice
>
> Empty slices are useful when you want to represent an empty collection, such as when a database query returns zero results.
>
> ```
> // Use make to create an empty slice of integers.
> slice := make([]int, 0)
>
> // Use a slice literal to create an empty slice of integers.
> slice := []int{}
> ```
>
> Regardless of whether you’re using a nil slice or an empty slice, the built-in functions `append`, `len`, and `cap` work the same.

---

[Go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/5bjyfO5OmB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var nil_slice []int
    var empty_slice = []int{}

    fmt.Println(nil_slice == nil, len(nil_slice), cap(nil_slice))
    fmt.Println(empty_slice == nil, len(empty_slice), cap(empty_slice))

}
```

prints:

```
true 0 0
false 0 0
```

Comment: Can we get the address of empty slice in one step using `make`?

Comment: If we take a look at the function [signature](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make), `make` doesn't seem to return the address. I believe you can't do it in one step.

Answer (score 18):

Empty slice and nil slice are initialized differently in Go:

```
var nilSlice []int 
emptySlice1 := make([]int, 0)
emptySlice2 := []int{}

fmt.Println(nilSlice == nil)    // true
fmt.Println(emptySlice1 == nil) // false
fmt.Println(emptySlice2 == nil) // false
```

As for all three slices, len and cap are 0.

Comment: `make([]int, 0)` is the best because Jetbrains GoLand does not complain about it being "unnecessary" as it does in the case of `[]int{}`. This is useful in writing unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ANisus' answer

When using the official [Go MongoDb Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver), a `nil` slice will also marshal into `"null"` whereas an empty slice will marshal into `"[]"`.

When using using the community supported [MGO driver](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo), both `nil` and empty slices will be marshalled into `"[]"`.

Reference: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-971