# How slice works in GO?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

```
a = make([]int, 7, 15)
```

creates implicit array of size `15` and slice(`a`) creates a shallow copy of implicit array and points to first 7 elements in array.

Consider,

```
var a []int;
```

creates a zero length slice that does not point to any implicit array.

```
a = append(a, 9, 86);
```

creates new implicit array of length 2 and append values `9` and `86`. slice(`a`) points to that new implicit array, where

`len(a) is 2` and `cap(a) >= 2`

---

My question:

is this the correct understanding?

Comment: You may want to work through the "Tour of Go" (tour.golang.org), especially the slice parts.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned "[Declare slice or make slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25544086/6309)",  the zero value of a slice (nil) acts like a zero-length slice.

So you can append to `a []int` directly.

You would need to make a slice (`make([]int, 0)` ) only if you wanted to potentially return an empty slice (instead of `nil`).
If not, no need to allocate memory before starting appending.
See also "[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append': Nil](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_11.)"

> a nil slice is functionally equivalent to a zero-length slice, even though it points to nothing. It has length zero and can be appended to, with allocation.